# HSQLDB column and table names in lowercases

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, hsqldb, flyway

I have a spring boot app which generates a schema with flyway in an hsqldb.

The problem is that all table and column names are converted to upper case (TBL_ROLE, ID, NAME).
The aim is to have the names in the db exactly like in my script defined.

Flyway script:

```
create table tbl_role (
  id integer not null, 
  name varchar(255), 
  default_layout varchar(255), 
  primary 
  key (id))
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_role")
public class Role {
  @Id
  private Integer id;

  private String name;
  ...
```

Hibernate Output:

```
org.hibernate.SQL                        : create table tbl_role (id integer not null, default_layout varchar(255), name varchar(255), possible_layouts varchar(255), primary key (id))
```

I tried to write the table and column names in double qoutes and single quotes but this didn't had any effect.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: I don't want to have to put all names in double quotes

Comment: "*table and column names are converted to upper case*" - which is what the SQL standard requires

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that the flyway scripts weren't executed. So the changes with the double quotes weren't applied.
Nevertheless it's not a perfect solution..